# Configuration Possibilties / Permutations

Tags: permutations, combinations

I have created 25 watercolor panels, each a different color, and they hang in a grid that is 5 panels across and 5 panels down. How many different configurations and/or sequences of the panels are possible - even if I change the position of just 2 panels? The 5 x 5 grid configuration must be maintained.

[image: image attached of the 25 panels]
I know the answer has a fairly simple equation - but I'm an artist out of math practice - and was curious as to the number of possible ways I can install this piece.
Thank you!

Comment: You have $25!\approx 1.55\cdot 10^{25}$ possibilities. That is an enormous number!

Comment: @Peter You may want to expand your comment to an answer.

Comment: Maybe, I misinterpreted the question. Do you want to know the number of possibilities to change a pair or the total number of possible configurations ?

Comment: While Peter delivered the answer you were most likely looking for, I'd like to highlight that we can arrange these panels in $25! \cdot 4^{25}$ ways if we allow rotations of the panels (noting that they're not invariant under any such rotation).

Comment: @Stefan Of course, this would largely increase the number of possibilities.

Comment: @Peter - thank you. Looking for the total number of possible different configurations.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you too!

Comment: Fun fact: There are roughly $7.5 \cdot 10^{18}$ grains of sand on planet earth. So even without rotating the panels you can arrange them in a different way for every grain of sand on earth and any grain of salt and ... I was hoping we came close to the number of atoms in the observable universe, but that's a whopping $10^{80}$ and even with rotating the panels we only end up with $\sim 1.7 \cdot 10^{40}$ combinations.

Comment: @Stefan Totally fun fact - love it! Thanks again! Relating (somewhat) to the whopping configurations - each 7 x 7 in. panel is a comprised of painting with a single color where I "trap" points of blank paper by painting around them in an improvised fashion. I count the points of "negative space" as they are trapped and make a mark for each 100 points.  The total count for each piece varies from 2,500 - 4,500 "points." I have created a much larger piece using a chromatic scale w/ 315 panels w/ over 10^6 "points of light." http://www.lawrencefodor.com/www.lawrencefodor.com/Holding_Light.html

Comment: Today I learned something new... I'm color blind, I see at most 10 colors there.

Answer (score 1):

If we number the positions and start placing the pieces, the first piece has $25$ places, the second $24$, the third $23$ and so on, so in total we have

$$25\cdot 24\cdot 23\cdots 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$$

possibilities. The product of the numbers $1$ to $n$ is well known in mathematics, it is called the factorial of $n$ and it is denoted with $n!$. Here, we have $25!$ possibilities , which is equal to $$15,511,210,043,330,985,984,000,000$$

Comment: Even if a computer would produce $10^{12}$ configurations per second, it woult take almost $500,000$ years until all configurations occured.

Comment: $25!$ is bigger than the number of bit strings of length $83$.

Comment: WOW! This is very helpful - and overwhelming at the same time! But it was the formula I was looking for! Thanks again.